# How do I find the default branch for a repository using the Github v3 API

Tags: github-api

My goal is to get the tree for the latest SHA in the default branch

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:sha
```

How do I find the lastest SHA from the default branch?

I know that I can call

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch
```

But I can't just use "master" for the branch as not all repos use master as the default branch.

How do I find out what the default branch for a repo is?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Make a call to `/repos/:owner/:repo` and read the `default_branch` property value - this is the name of the default branch. See example response here: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get

Comment: 100% this. Also if you're using any good wrapper library, they should all give you easy access to this.

Comment: There is actually "default_branch" key.

Comment: @android Hey, you're right -- there are two keys: the `master_branch` key and the `default_branch` key. Do you know what the difference is? I'm guessing they'll both have the same value always, and that one key was deprecated at some point in time.

Comment: @android at times `default_branch` is empty (nil) while `master_branch` isn't and at other times neither is empty. I haven't been able to discover a reason for it yet and frankly don't feel it's important enough to bug the API team about it.

Comment: `master_branch` only exists for backwards compatibility. `default_branch` will replace `master_branch` in the [next version of the API](http://developer.github.com/#expected-changes).

Comment: "at times default_branch is empty (nil) while master_branch isn't and at other times neither is empty." => They should always have the same value. If you see a place where they have different values, please [let us know](https://github.com/contact).

Answer (score 4):

This is also now avaialable with the [**github cli**](https://cli.github.com/) as well

```sh
gh repo list <Your_Name> --json nameWithOwner,defaultBranchRef
```

If you want to *slightly cleanup* the output, you can remap with [**jq**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```sh
gh repo list <Your_Name> --json nameWithOwner,defaultBranchRef \
  --jq ".[] | { nameWithOwner , defaultBranch: .defaultBranchRef.name}"
```

The advantage to this approach being auth is integrated and much easier to manage

Answer (score 2):

This is a cleaner and faster way using gh:

```
gh api repos/{owner}/{repo} --jq '.default_branch'
```

(in Git Bash leading slashes cause it to be interpreted as a local absolute path)