# Get the hash of the current HEAD of a repository using only HTTP

Tags: git, github

I know that if I have a Git repository checked out, I can use the `git` CLI to get the current commit hash. But is there a way to do this just over HTTP, without cloning the repository?

For example, let's say that I want to get the current hash of https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript. Manually, I can go to the page, press `Y` on my keyboard, and see that the hash is (at the time of this writing) `1f197fcc1bf1a15bc45a6b23fb3f706ffcb77025`. Which means that if at some later point I wanted to download the CoffeeScript source as it is at this moment, I could download https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/archive/1f197fcc1bf1a15bc45a6b23fb3f706ffcb77025.zip, and it would give me the source.

Is there a way to do this just using HTTP (e.g. curl)? Can I hit some endpoint which will tell me what the current hash is of the default branch? Generalizing a bit, are there endpoints which will tell me the hash of

- The HEAD of the default branch,
- the HEAD of a given branch, or
- a particular tag?

Comment: I have implemented a small utility to do just that (find the SHA1 of a GitHub repo). See my [edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30815863/6309)

Comment: Without cloning? `git ls-remote u://r/l HEAD`.  No need to restrict yourself to just http, this gets the hashes over any git transport, from any repo you can reach.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted this information on GitHub specifically, you could retrieve it using [the GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get-branch), which will return a somewhat large JSON structure with exhaustive information on the state of that branch:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/jashkenas/coffeescript/branches/master
```

(Or remove the branch name to get a more terse listing of all branches and their heads.)

For Git repositories hosted on other web services, it's possible to fetch the resource `/info/refs` under the repository (e.g, `http://example.com/repo.git/info/refs`) to get a listing of all branches, e.g.:

```
2aae6c35c94fcfb415dbe95f408b9ce91ee846ed    refs/heads/master
```

However, **this is not available on GitHub**, because [GitHub disabled the "dumb" HTTP transport in 2011](https://github.com/blog/809-git-dumb-http-transport-to-be-turned-off-in-90-days) for performance reasons. The replacement "smart" transport, while far superior for Git's own use, isn't usable outside that context.

Comment: You can still use `/info/refs` even with smart http, as that's the first step in negotiation.  If GitHub has blocked dumb http very aggressively, then append `?service=git-upload-pack` to the URL query refs like a smart http client.

Comment: GitHub has indeed blocked the dumb HTTP transport quite aggressively. Adding `?service=git-upload-pack` changes the data in some surprising ways; I think there's some kind of encapsulation added.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's true.  `git ls-remote` should parse that additional metadata properly, in that case.

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use the [GitHub API Reference](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/) to query the SHA1 of:

- branches (example: https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/git/refs/heads)
- tags (example: https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/git/refs/tags/v1.7.0)

In each case, you get a JSON answer similar to (for a given tag for instance)

```
{
  "ref": "refs/tags/v1.7.0",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/git/refs/tags/v1.7.0",
  "object": {
    "sha": "15c6c83c4950d80e6bbabc5186c90b35629ce4f7",
    "type": "tag",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/git/tags/15c6c83c4950d80e6bbabc5186c90b35629ce4f7"
  }
}
```

Note: to get the HEAD (in GitHub, called "default branch"), see "[How do I find the default branch for a repository using the Github v3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16501903/6309)" (and [repos get](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get))

> Make a call to `/repos/:owner/:repo` and read the `master_branch` property value - this is the name of the default branch.

Example: https://api.github.com/repos/git/git

```
"default_branch": "master",
```

---

I have implemented a short Go program which does just that (find the SHA1 of a GitHub repo reference)

See [**VonC/ghref**](https://github.com/VonC/ghref)

- to find the default branch of a GitHub repo

  ```
  vonc@voncm:~/prog/git/ghref$ bin/ghref VonC/ghref
  master
  ```
- to find the SHA1 of a branch of a GitHub repo

  ```
  vonc@voncm:~/prog/git/ghref$ bin/ghref VonC/ghref master
  c024c28ff3e17cd6864c6d692845860b4c3d8003
  ```
- it works with tags too:

  ```
  vonc@voncm:~/prog/git/ghref$ bin/ghref VonC/ghref v1.1.0
  59a4be1888c2e8d9f7c83892c4c16b92cc333328         (^^^^^^)
  ```
- to find the SHA1 of the *default* branch of a GitHub repo:

  ```
  vonc@voncm:~/prog/git/ghref$ bin/ghref VonC/ghref | xargs bin/ghref VonC/ghref
  c024c28ff3e17cd6864c6d692845860b4c3d8003
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This command appears to be what you are looking for.

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript
```

You can parse the SHA-1 hash out from the line that ends with HEAD and carriage return.

E.g. using [`grep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) to show you the line I am talking about:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript | grep "HEAD$"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit), `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/:sha` should get you the current SHA-1 hash and more.

You can [get a tag](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/#get-a-tag) with this: `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/tags/:sha`