# GitHub API - latest branch commit has been pushed into the master?

Tags: git, github

How can you check if the latest branch commit has been pushed into the master via the Github API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the [GitHub API "Refs"](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#get-a-reference)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/refs/:ref
```

I showed (in 2015) a [more complete example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30815863/6309).

But don't forget a simple git ls-remote would also show you the latest commits of the remote repo branches.

Compare that with "[How to retrieve the hash for the current commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949391/6309)"

```
git rev-parse master
```

And you can check if that local `master` HEAD commit has been pushed or not.

Comment: @JaySlack I have edited the answer to address your comment.