# How to list files of the default branch for a repository using the Github API via one query?

Tags: github-api

Related problem: [How do I find the default branch for a repository using the Github v3 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500461/how-do-i-find-the-default-branch-for-a-repository-using-the-github-v3-api)

**Different** from the related problem, I want to **list the files** of the default branch.

The API I know to list files of the `master` branch is:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo_name/git/trees/master
```

However, the default branch name could be `main`.

Is there a way to list files of the default branch **through only one query**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use HEAD simply (which refers to the default remote branch).

I tried it using [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) after a ([`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login))

```
gh api repos/owner/repo_name/git/trees/HEAD
```

Example:

```
gh api repos/VonC/gitcred/git/trees/HEAD --jq ".tree[].path"
```